Matlab-support package: how to make it point to a new MATLAB version?
I have been using MATLAB on an Ubuntu desktop for a few years now. I found that the package https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/matlab-support that was readily available in the "Software" menu very handy as it gives a convenient way to start MATLAB and run it run smoothly.
Now I want to upgrade the version of MATLAB. I have downloaded the new version. But I am unable to let matlab-support connect to the new version. Even if I remove and reinstall, it keeps restarting the old MATLAB version.
in addition, I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and I want to go from Matlab R2020b to R2024b. I downloaded and unzipped the installer files and let the install script run. In my directory usr/local/MATLAB , I now have two subdirectories: R2020b and R2024b. I could try to remove R2020b but want to avoid the risk of having no working installation available.

You've provided little for us to provide specific help with, we don't know what Ubuntu Desktop version you're asking about; how you installed MatLab as you mention only a newer version without specifics.

@guiverc thanks, added details

Check you've been applying security fixes & other updates; as 20.04.3 implies you've not done so since before Feb-2022; ie. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date of 20.04.4, but installed systems upgraded BEFORE that date (a fully upgraded system no longer reports as 20.04.4 either)

@guiverc updated. There was a problem connecting to the update server, but managed to resolve it by unchecking a few "other software" boxes in the software & update settings. Nothing that seems MATLAB related
